# wordpress returning 404 in permalink post name on plesk onyx 17.8

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404, plesk, plesk-onyx

Im having an issue with wordpress (im kinda new)

i have a domain in godaddy and it has plesk onyx 17.8, it does not ahve apache it has IIS and i made a wordpress blog example on my localhost and uploaded to my domain to test it, when i use the permalinks option of post name, instead of plain, all other pages besides the home return 404, but plain works with no problem. i try changing th .htaccess file as i have seen in many places with no luck. And as i have said before plesk 17.8 does not run apache. The only other sources that i found mentioning the IIS option, led me to do some changes on the web.config that had no results.

my web.config file to date

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <configuration>
 <system.webServer>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
        <rule name="WordPress: http://www.mauricioalbanese.com" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
            <match url="*"/>
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
        </rule></rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

my .htaccess to date:

```
 # BEGIN WordPress
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
 </IfModule>
 # END WordPress
```

i dont know what else can be causing this, please help

everything is inside my root folder were my original web page is stored.

Answer (score 0):

so after some research i figured it out... and the problem is not with wordpress but with my hosting admin platform.

i was using plesk with godaddy and it seems that wordpress has some issues with plesk and some features do not work well will with it.

i changed to cpanel and problem solved.

so i recomend you talk to your host provider and make sure witch platform supports wordpress best before you go and use it.